# Paypal Donations on Angular/Bootstrap site;

Tags: html, angularjs, paypal

I'm creating an Angular/Bootstrap website for a non-profit, which will be accepting donations via Paypal.

On the website, the following options would appear via radio buttons;
Donation Frequency: Weekly, Monthly or Yearly
Donation Amount: $10, $50, $100, $200, $500 or Other ('other' the user would enter via a text box).
Direct Donation: General Purpose, Youth Programs, Adult Programs or Specific Use ('Specific Use' the user would enter via a text box where to direct the donation).

So my question -
If I create a Subscription Button, it wants me to set 'x' amount (donation Amount) when creating the button... i can though create the the frequency.
Additionally, I can't get it to set the 'Direct Donation' as to the payment purpose (it wants the user to enter text here on Paypal).

Is there a way to get around these problems?
Should I use a different type of button?
Or Do I need to use the API here?

- Obviously im getting it to display a different button icon on the website, rather than the 'subscribe' icon, as this is for donations.

Here's some sample code for the button at the moment;

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="V7E299NH9JGC2">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Donation Amount">Donation Amount</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
    <option value="$10">$10 </option>
    <option value="$50">$50 </option>
    <option value="$100">$100 </option>
    <option value="$200">$200 </option>
    <option value="$500">$500 </option>
</select> </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Frequency">Frequency</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os1">
    <option value="Weekly">Weekly </option>
    <option value="Monthly">Monthly </option>
    <option value="Yearly">Yearly </option>
</select> </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on2" value="Direct Donation">Direct Donation</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os2">
    <option value="General Purposes">General Purposes </option>
    <option value="Youth Programs">Youth Programs </option>
    <option value="Audult Programs">Audult Programs </option>
    <option value="Specific Use">Specific Use </option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_AU/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_AU/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Answer to my own question here...
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/html_example_subscribe/#basic-subscribe-button

But anyway, my code is starting to look like this...

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">

    <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="*********">

    <!-- Specify a Subscribe button. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
    <!-- Identify the subscription. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Youth Program">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Youth Programs">

    <!-- Set the terms of the regular subscription. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AUD">

    <input type="radio" name="a3" value="$10"> $10
    <input type="radio" name="a3" value="$50"> $50
    <input type="radio" name="a3" value="$100"> $100
    <input type="radio" name="a3" value="$200"> $200
    <input type="radio" name="a3" value="$500"> $500
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
    <input type="radio" name="t3" value="W"> Weekly
    <input type="radio" name="t3" value="M"> Monthly
    <input type="radio" name="t3" value="Y"> Yearly
    <br>

    <!-- Set recurring payments until canceled. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">

    <!-- Display the payment button. -->
    <input type="image" name="submit"
    src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_AU/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif"
    alt="Subscribe">
    <img alt="" width="1" height="1"
    src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
</form>
```

The radio buttons for Amount & Frequency work, and just need to create a Radio Button for the description.

Answer (score -1):

Its very easy to do. Follow the directions found here to create a new button that will include a text field, option, dropdown or whatever you like that would allow donater to choose where to direct donation.

Documentation can be found below:

https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/get-started/donate-button-text-field

If my answer helped you please accept it :)

Answer (score -1):

The challenge here is how to do a 'DONATE' button using angular and not a checkout button. simply adding the paypal generated donate button form tag inside an angular template is just not working.